# How to publish Blazor WASM Core Hosted using Web Deploy from local Visual Studio 2022 to IIS in a remote W2012 server?

Tags: visual-studio, iis, blazor, blazor-webassembly, windows-server-2012

I just deployed my first Blazor WASM app. Everything is working fine but I'm wondering if I could automate the process of publishing.

Currently the process is:

Publish to folder on local machine

Zip the folder

Copy to remote server

Unzip

Replace files on app folder except the web.config and appsettings.json

The app is published as a sub application on IIS 8.5 running on a Windows Server 2012 machine

I tried to follow this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IkveZO9TZtU) but I don't see the "Configure Web Deploy Publishing" option at min 14:50, I can see it if I right click on the parent site but not on the sub application.

Comment: IIS does not support Web Deployment on sub-applications. You can manually create a web deployment package and then use a method (such as FTP, SCP, RDP) to transfer the web deployment package (ZIP file) to a remote server.
On the remote server, unzip the web deployment package. This is similar to your current process.